# Name of principal root function modified to return real values if possible

Tags: functions, terminology

Is there a concise name for the function $f_n(x)\colon\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ which returns the principal $n$th root of $x$, except in the case when $n$ is odd and $x$ is a negative real number, in which case the real root is returned?